# How to print image or Pdf file using TSC DA200 Printer?

Tags: java, android, pdf, printing

I am printing the bitmap successfully, but not able to print image on the 4*4 page and want to print the pdf file. But not found anything to print the pdf file.

I am using this code

```
             TscUSB.openport(mUsbManager,device);

             TscUSB.setup(101 , 101 , 4, 15, 0, 3 , 0);
             TscUSB.clearbuffer();


             TscUSB.sendcommand("TEXT 0,0,\"1\",0,1,1,\"\"\r\n");

             Bitmap myLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.qr);
             TscUSB.sendpicture(250,250,myLogo);
             TscUSB.sendcommand("PRINT 1\r\n");
             TscUSB.closeport(3000);
```

Comment: Arjun sir I think Google Cloud print option may be solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check first whether your printer support PDF printing or Not? If your printer does not support pdf print then you could try getting bytes from a pdf file & send them to printer. But this approach you may not getting proper format as output.
2. To print image: Convert your image into Bitmap and then sent it to printer